Issues with std::vector.size() --> Slow and delayed program start
I'm learning C++ and I wanted to program a small simulation of colliding circles in SFML. Everything was fine, collisions between a circle and a wall worked. But then I wanted to write the code for collisions between the circles.
There is a std::vector within all the existing circles named "circles". I wrote two for-loops to proof for every pair of circles, if they collide:
for (int i = 0; i < circles.size() - 1; i++)
        {
            MovingCircle& circle1 = circles[i];
            for (int j = i + 1; j < circles.size(); j++)
            {
                MovingCircle& circle2 = circles[j];

                // Collision detection and calculating the velocities after collision
            }
        }

MovingCircle is a struct:
struct MovingCircle
{
    sf::CircleShape shape;
    sf::Vector2f direction;
    float speed;
};

But after I wrote the two for-loops, the program startet really slow, after compiling and linking. When the program has been started, it runs smooth. But the start is very slow and delayed.
Then I changed my code to this:
int circlesSize = circles.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < circlesSize - 1; i++)
        {
            MovingCircle& circle1 = circles[i];
            for (int j = i + 1; j < circlesSize; j++)
            {
                MovingCircle& circle2 = circles[j];

                // Collision detection and calculating the velocities after collision
            }
        }

And it worked. The program starts without delay. But why? Is the calculation of the vector's size so hard?
I've tried to ask ChatGPT, but it didn't give me an satisfying answer. I understand, that in my original code, the size was calculated every loop. But why was the start of the program so slow and from the moment it has been started it ran smooth?
Here is the complete code:
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

struct MovingCircle
{
    sf::CircleShape shape;
    sf::Vector2f direction;
    float speed;
};

MovingCircle createCircle(sf::Vector2i mousePos, sf::Color color)
{
    MovingCircle newCircle;
    newCircle.shape = sf::CircleShape(25.0);
    newCircle.shape.setOrigin(
        newCircle.shape.getRadius(),
        newCircle.shape.getRadius());
    newCircle.shape.setPosition(
        static_cast<float>(mousePos.x),
        static_cast<float>(mousePos.y));
    newCircle.shape.setFillColor(color);
    return newCircle;
}

sf::Vector2f normalizeVector(sf::Vector2f vector)
{
    float length = std::sqrt(std::pow(vector.x, 2) + std::pow(vector.y, 2));
    return vector / length;
}

float calculateScalarProduct(sf::Vector2f vector1, sf::Vector2f vector2)
{
    return vector1.x * vector2.x + vector1.y * vector2.y;
}

float calculateNormOfVector(sf::Vector2f vector)
{
    return std::sqrt(std::pow(vector.x, 2) + std::pow(vector.y, 2));
}

float calculateLength(sf::Vector2f vector)
{
    return std::sqrt(std::pow(vector.x, 2) + std::pow(vector.y, 2));
}

sf::Vector2f calculateProjection(sf::Vector2f a, sf::Vector2f b)
{
    // Projektion von a auf b
    float scalarProduct_ab = calculateScalarProduct(a, b);
    float scalarProduct_bb = calculateScalarProduct(b, b);
    float scale = scalarProduct_ab / scalarProduct_bb;
    return scale * b;
}

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd; // für den Seed
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); // mit Seed initialisieren
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0, 255);

    std::vector<MovingCircle> circles;

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1000, 1000), "Ballspiel v2");
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);
    sf::View view = window.getDefaultView();

    // Um später zu prüfen, ob bereits eine circlePos erstellt wurde,
    // wird ein Standardwert (-1, -1) festgelegt:
    // Solange der Standardwert zugewiesen ist, gibt es noch keine
    // festgelegte circlePos
    sf::Vector2i circlePos = sf::Vector2i(-1, -1);

    sf::VertexArray line(sf::Lines, 2);

    MovingCircle newCircle;

    float speedFactor = 0.05;

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // EVENTS
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();

            if (event.type == sf::Event::Resized)
            {
                sf::FloatRect visibleArea(0, 0, event.size.width, event.size.height);
                window.setView(sf::View(visibleArea));
            }

            if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed)
            {
                if (event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left)
                {
                    // Es gibt schon eine circlePos
                    if (circlePos != sf::Vector2i(-1, -1))
                    {
                        sf::Vector2f direction = line[0].position - line[1].position;
                        circles.back().direction = normalizeVector(direction);
                        circles.back().speed = calculateLength(direction);
                        circlePos = sf::Vector2i(-1, -1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Es gibt noch keine circlePos
                        // circlePos = (-1, -1)
                        circlePos = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
                        sf::Color color(dist(gen), dist(gen), dist(gen));
                        newCircle = createCircle(circlePos, color);
                        circles.push_back(newCircle);
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            
        }

        // UPDATE
        if (circlePos != sf::Vector2i(-1, -1))
        {
            sf::Vector2i mousePos = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
            line[0].position = sf::Vector2f(
                static_cast<float>(circlePos.x),
                static_cast<float>(circlePos.y));
            line[1].position = sf::Vector2f(
                static_cast<float>(mousePos.x),
                static_cast<float>(mousePos.y));
        }

        for (auto& circle : circles)
        {
            // Prüfung, ob Kreis in x-Richtung mit Rand kollidiert
            if (circle.shape.getPosition().x > 975.0)
            {
                circle.direction = circle.direction
                    - 2 * calculateScalarProduct(circle.direction, sf::Vector2f(-1.0, 0.0)) * sf::Vector2f(-1.0, 0.0);                 
            }
            else if (circle.shape.getPosition().x < 25.0)
            {
                circle.direction = circle.direction
                    - 2 * calculateScalarProduct(circle.direction, sf::Vector2f(1.0, 0.0)) * sf::Vector2f(1.0, 0.0); 
            }

            // Prüfung, ob Kreis in y-Richtung mit Rand kollidiert
            if (circle.shape.getPosition().y > 975.0)
            {
                circle.direction = circle.direction
                    - 2 * calculateScalarProduct(circle.direction, sf::Vector2f(0.0, -1.0)) * sf::Vector2f(0.0, -1.0);                 
            }
            else if (circle.shape.getPosition().y < 25.0)
            {
                circle.direction = circle.direction
                    - 2 * calculateScalarProduct(circle.direction, sf::Vector2f(0.0, 1.0)) * sf::Vector2f(0.0, 1.0); 
            }
        }

        int circlesSize = circles.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < circlesSize - 1; i++)
        {
            MovingCircle& circle1 = circles[i];
            for (int j = i + 1; j < circlesSize; j++)
            {
                MovingCircle& circle2 = circles[j];

                // Collision detection and calculating the velocities after collision
            }
        }

        for (auto& circle : circles)
        {
            circle.shape.move(circle.direction * circle.speed * speedFactor);
        }

        
        
        // DRAW
        window.clear();

        if (circlePos != sf::Vector2i(-1, -1))
        {
            window.draw(line);
        }
        

        for (auto& circle : circles)
        {
            window.draw(circle.shape);
        }
        


        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}


Questions about performance and optimisation should always include how you compiled the program. Particularly: did you turn optimisation on? With which flag?

Partial answer: to help the compiler figure out what is happening, you should traverse the vector through a const ref so it doesn't have to check for iterator / cache invalidation.

Comment from SG: If circles is empty, circles.size()-1 is a huge number. Have you checked it?

If you are using visual studio (windows), you can use the profiler that comes with it to find the bottlenecks.

for (int i = 0; i < circles.size() - 1; i++) -- int circlesSize = circles.size(); -- I'm learning C++ -- If you're learning C++, you shouldn't ignore the warning(s) the compiler is giving you for those lines of code.  Did the compiler tell you that you are comparing/assigning unsigned with signed integers?  As mentioned, if circles.size() is empty, what value is circles.size() - 1?

I've tried to ask ChatGPT, -- You should be debugging your code to know exactly what lines of code are causing the issue.  Single-step using a debugger to pinpoint when and where the slow-down is taking place.
